# In group with order of $pq$ what are the possible values for order of an element?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I have to find the possible values for $o(a)$.here is my question:

Suppose $(G,*)$ is a group with $o(G)=pq$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes. For any $a\in G$ find alll possible values of $o(a)$

I can't figure it out. any one can give me a hint

Comment: By Lagrange, it is either $1, p, q$ or $pq$, can you find an example of each?

Comment: I haven't learnt the theorem.

Comment: Do you know that the order of a subgroup divides the order of the group?

Comment: No. I don't know

Comment: In what context does this question arise that Lagrange's theorem is not available?

Comment: I was doing some past papers of my algebra course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint:* Note that $o(a)=|\langle a \rangle|$ and use [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)).

Actually, all you need is this result:

> If $G$ is a finite group and $a \in G$, then the order of $a$ divides the order of $G$.

The simplest proof I know is this: take $a \in G$ and consider the map $f\colon G \to G$ given by $f(x)=ax$. Consider now the *orbits* of $f$, that is, the sets $\mathcal{O}(x)=\{ x, f(x), f(f(x)), \dots \} = \{ x, ax, a^2x, \dots \}$. All orbits have the same number of elements because $z\mapsto zx^{-1}y$ is a bijection $\mathcal{O}(x) \to \mathcal{O}(y)$. By definition, $|\mathcal{O}(e)| = o(a)$. Hence $o(a)$ divides $|G|$ because $G$ is the disjoint union of orbits.

Going back to your problem, we conclude that the possible orders of an element in $G$ are $1,p,q,pq$.

You'll learn later that every group of order $pq$ has an element of order $p$ and an element of order $q$ (a result called Cauchy's theorem), but not necessarily an element of order $pq$ if $G$ is not abelian.

Comment: [I wish I knew](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28332/is-lagranges-theorem-the-most-basic-result-in-finite-group-theory) a direct proof  that does not depend on Lagrange's theorem.