# If $G$ is a group of order $p^n$, with $p$ prime and $n>1$. Prove that the order of every element of $G$ is a power of $p$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

Here is my approach:

If $a\in G$, let's consider a subgroup $H=[a]$. Lagrange's theorem tell us that $o(H) \mid p^n$. But since $p$ is prime, the order $H$ must be the power $p\leq n$, with $k\leq n$. In particular, $o(a)=p^k$

Comment: We don't need to write $o(H)$ of "de subgroup" anymore, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452762/order-of-group-element-divides-order-of-finite-group). By Lagrange, the order $o(g)$ divides $p^n$, and hence is itself a prime power $p^k$.

Comment: Even if $G$ is not cyclic?

Comment: A group of prime power order is not cyclic in general. So yes, for all finite groups, see the duplicate in my comment.

Comment: Actually when I said "de", I should have written "a".

Comment: Yes, I know. Probably it came from a Spanish text? Ah, Portuguese!

Comment: Portuguese... I am Brazilian

Comment: @DietrichBurde $Z_9$ is group whose order is 9 which is a power of 3 and is cyclic same is true for any $Z_{p^n}$ group.

Comment: @grey $C_p\times C_p$ is a group of order $p^2$, but is not cyclic. A group of order $p^3$ even need not be abelian. Think of the Heisenberg group over $\Bbb F_p$. So again: " A group of prime power order is not cyclic in general."

Comment: @DietrichBurde what do you mean when you say "in general"? I'm a bit curious about this.

Comment: @grey "Not cyclic in general" means, not necessarily cyclic. This is a standard formulation in mathematics. Even integers are not divisible by four in general - means, that an integer like $2$ or $6$ is not divisible by $4$, but $8$ is divisible by $4$, for example.