# A(S) mappings onto itself

Tags: abstract-algebra

This problem is from abstract algebra and I am trying to solve but I am completely lost. The problem is as follows:

If $f\in S_3$, show that $f^6 = I$.

This section has to do with $A(S)$, the set of $1$ to $1$ mappings of $S$ onto itself. The textbook's answer is $S=\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$ and $f\in S_3$ and $f(x_1)\neq x_1$. Since there are only a finite number of choices in $S$, either $f^2(x_1) = x_1$ or $f^3(x_1) = x_1$. This is similar for $x_2$ and $x_3$, $f$ satisfies $f^2(x)=x$ or $f^3(x)=x$. This gives $f^6(x)=x$ for all members of $S$.

I don't understand this answer could someone please elaborate?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. How do you think of $S_3$? How many elements does it have? Can you write them all out? Can you then raise them all to the $6$th power?

Comment: I have no clue, im really stuck on this one

Comment: Please check whatever notes or textbook you have. It is impossible to prove results about things that you cannot even define. At minimum, please find a definition for $S_3$.

Comment: its a set with three elements

Comment: That's not quite right. The group $S_3$ should have $6$ elements.

Comment: 3!, ok that helps a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say $f \in S_3$.

Then $f$'s reason in life is to permute a three element set. That is $f$ should be some bijection
from $\{x_1, x_2, x_3\}$ to itself.

> For instance, we might have $f(x_1) = x_1$, $f(x_2) = x_3$, and $f(x_3) = x_2$.

If this isn't clear you should spend some time rereading whatever part of your book or notes introduced the [symmetric groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group).

---

Now, what does it mean for $f^6 = I$? If this is what we're trying to prove, we had better understand the statement!

Well $I$ is the *identity mapping* that just fixes all the elements. So $I(x_1) = x_1$, $I(x_2) = x_2$ and $I(x_3) = x_3$.

Next, $f^n$ is the map we get by applying $f$ $n$-many times. So for instance, $f^3(x_2) = f(f(f(x_2)))$.

> Now, you should take a moment and *check this by hand* for at least two examples.
>
> 1. If $f$ fixes $x_1$ and swaps $x_2$ and $x_3$, manually compute $f^6(x_1)$, $f^6(x_2)$, and $f^6(x_3)$. Check that in each case $f^6(x) = I(x) = x$
> 2. If $f(x_1) = x_2$, $f(x_2) = x_3$, and $f(x_3) = x_1$, do the same thing. Manually compute $f^6$ on each input and verify that it agrees with $I$.

At this point, since there's only $6$ elements of $S_3$, you could (in theory) just check all of them! But what if somebody asked you to prove a similar theorem about $S_{100,000}$? Is there a more clever approach that saves you having to check all the cases?

---

The answer, of course, is *yes*! The idea is to figure out a power high enough to *guarantee* that $f^n(x) = I(x) = x$ for each $x_1$, $x_2,$ and $x_3$.

Let's look at $x_1$ -- all the other cases are the same.

If $f(x_1) = x_1$, then we're done.

If $f(x_1) = y \neq x_1$, then we only have two options. Either $f(y) = x_1$, or $f(y) = z$.

$\quad \quad$ If $f(y) = x_1$, then we see $f^2(x_1) = f(f(x_1)) f(y) = x_1$, and we're done.

$\quad \quad$ If $f(y) = z$, then since $f$ is a bijection, we must have $f(z) = x_1$ (do you see why?). In this case, $f^3(x_1) = x_1$.

So we know that either $f$, $f^2$, or $f^3$ fixes $x_1$.

But if $f^2(x_1) = x_1$, then $f^6(x_1) = f^2(f^2(f^2(x_1))) = x_1$ too. Similarly, if $f^3(x_1) = x_1$, then $f^6(x_1) = f^3(f^3(x_1)) = x_1$!

So no matter what, we see that $f^6(x_1) = x_1$!

Of course, nothing was special about $x_1$ here, and the exact same argument shows that $f^6(x_2) = x_2$ and $f^6(x_3) = x_3$.

So for all inputs, $f^6(x_i) = x_i = I(x_i)$, so $f^6 = I$. Exactly what we set out to prove.

---

As an aside, this can be generalized quite far! In fact, for *any* finite group $G$, $x^{|G|} = 1$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1452762/order-of-group-element-divides-order-of-finite-group), for instance.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: +1 for "$f$'s reason in life is to permute a three element set". xD

Comment: the case of f(y)=z is puzzling me, can you elaborate?

Comment: I do not see why f(z)=$x_1$

Comment: I very intentionally left that as an exercise (this is why I said "do you see why?"). I suggest you work out some concrete examples to see why this is the case ^_^. As a hint, $f$ is a bijection, so it's injective. If $f(z) \neq x_1$, can you show that $f$ would not be injective?

Comment: I have verified the examples but they part of the solution that describes $f(x_1)\neq x_1$ is confusing